# How does one build reputation as an expert in the programming field?

Tags: clients, reputation

In a previous answer here on workplace, someone once responded to a different question saying, Be patient. Building up a network of potential clients takes time, and it involves you proving yourself to be a valuable expert in your field. This doesn't happen overnight, and it involves reputation. (Er, not Stack Overflow reputation, but real life reputation).

How does one build reputation as an expert in your field, "real world"? What does that look like if say you are some type of programmer in a particular language?

Comment: It's a shame this excellent question (now with diverse, excellent answers) is close voted.

Comment: Goto meet-ups in your city and present your work.  Start an influential open source product.  Be mean in a funny way on the internet.  This is going to be very specific to your personality and your specific skillset.

Comment: @Fattie, I would have to agree with you regarding my question.

Comment: @sevensevens, mean in a funny way? I was never raised to be mean, not sure what that does, but will see if there are any meetups near me. I do not live in a large city and will be moving into an even smaller region by end of 2022. Would love to present my work anywhere anyone is interested to hear and see it.

Comment: The flip side is that being an expert is short lived. It is surprising just how quickly the field changes and what I am an expert in - nobody wants to hear about any more. So, I question your goal. It may be better to be someone who solves business problems.

Comment: do you want to be regarded as an expert by peers or a wider audience?

Comment: @Kilisi, that is an excellent question. I think I have been focusing on the former with the idea of somehow developing a business model for retail customers that I am slowly growing. Fortune 500 type of companies just seem to be too smart for me, they know it all.

Comment: @Kilisi, interesting, can you give me an example of how you reach out to the wider audience?

Comment: @Kilisi, also I wonder if you ever heard of this guy online who talks a lot about consulting where you don't actually do work with your hands but they just pick your brain. He never completely convinced me. Yeah we have this buggy bubble sorting algorithm, yeah thats because your guys need to refactor it and place all that logic in a separate class...that will be 400 bucks please. Really?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123264/discussion-between-daniel-and-kilisi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, one of the best ways to gain reputation is by public speaking. Start looking for local user groups, remote Zoom based conferences, and then like. I've found that local groups are often looking for speakers, and it's a good way to gain name recognition on your field.

This means that you need to find an angle to sell yourself. Be the "What's new in LanguageX or Popular Framework Y" guy, or the "Patterns for web app architecture" guy. Whatever. Give talks, the same again and again and also newer ones.

Comment: I can relate to what you are saying. I have articles on Medium, but finding people who want me to talk I have yet to find anywhere, but your answer seems actionable and I have worked towards it, just not seeing anyone who wants to hear me talk. I did apply to a JSNation Live type of talk, twice and both my proposals were turned down. Let me see if there is something more local, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to keep in mind is that you need to be mindful of who you're building your reputation up with. Having a reputation *among developers* as being a good developer isn't very useful because developers are not likely to be looking to contract out to other devs.

The people who's reputation matters are business owners (or at least prospective ones). And you build up your reputation by doing things that they'd do. Maybe your city has entrepreneur meetups that you could attend (look people up on meetup.com). In my experience, sales people who go to meetups often have ideas, as well, and some modicum of money to throw around.

Another related strategy would be to help people with requests on github or support communities for specific products. Like get involved with the Magento community if you're a PHP dev and start providing lots of help for Magento and then offer paid support as well. Magento or some other e-commerce thing is key because people using Magento, in particular, are usually budding entrepreneurs looking to make money, whereas users of, say, OpenSSL, are devs. Like Adobe spent $1.68B USD to acquire Magento. Ain't no one looking to spend a billion dollars on OpenSSL. OpenSSL is lucky if they get $100,000 for being "critical infrastructure".

The average dev may look down on Magento but the average business owner has never even heard of OpenSSL so being an OpenSSL expert isn't gonna get you as far, money wise, as being a Magento expert will.

Comment: I love the superb *dollar specific* advice in para 3.  BTW, via further comments, it appears OP is, particularly, hurting from the "gatekeeper" angle.  (Fortunately, that is easily solved by studying and applying the well-known techniques for dealing with gatekeepers.)

Comment: FWIW where I live (small-medium sized college town) I know several people who successfully got started in software and PM by attending the dev meetups, but zero who got anywhere attending the enterpreneur events, as the budding entrepreneurs tended to give their tech (and legal, patent, accounting etc) work within the network of the people who run the local "incubator" and gatekeep the financing. Although the enterp's can still be interesting and educational.

Comment: @Fattie, actually that is incorrect. I am not having trouble with gatekeepers, I am having trouble with value vampires or time wasters. People that say hey I saw you on such and such and you have the skills and I am on the third conversation, they are having me do shadow work, change your resume to say this, now change it to say that and I have still not gotten in front of the actual "client". To be clear this does not actually happen to me, but if I allowed it, it would. So I guess I am asking, how do I get those fools out of my way and only get in front of the person with the purse strings.

Comment: @Fattie, quick real world example, the above scenario recently happened. It has not happened in a long time, but this "recruiter" really thinks he is going to take me for a time wasting ride. Had me send him resumes from two different sites I have, then proceed to ask me to convert one to another file extension, then tell me what I need to change on the resume. All the while, I already applied directly to the position he brought up with the company he mentioned. So my resume is now in front of the right eyes and this "recruiter" is still yanking my chain. How do I get that guy out of my life?

Comment: @neubert, your answer is thoughtful in general because I have been wanting to get in front of entrepreneurs, not just to become known and be their consultant, but to have people I can related to. I used to own a business and once you do that, your mindset does tend to be a bit different than someone who has never owned their own business. So not necessarily looking for fortune 500 owners, could just be a local food truck guy or t-shirt printing guy, anyone that has any semblance of owning a business. It seems rare these days to run into people who have any self-employed experience at all.

Comment: @Daniel not a single part of your comments to this answer is even hinted in the question. I'm not sure what you think you wrote in the question - you may want to re-read it and possibly ask totally different one.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, no the comments are different to the question. I was merely engaging in the offshoot topics that resulted, like the whole thing about gatekeepers, never was that a part of my original question.

Comment: @Daniel , regarding your anecdote about recruiters just above.  It's completely normal. Recruiters are idiots.  Everyone (in all industries) has anecdotes like that.  Nothing surprising.  As I mention below, if you don't want to, just *don't deal with recruiters*.    Click on "Jobs" to the left of this text and there are *a hundred* jobs you can apply for immediately, no connection to recruiters.  Best of luck

Comment: @Daniel , it is good form on here to stay on topic.  just ask new questions!

Comment: @Daniel, The key is to avoid 3rd party recruiters like the plague (unless they come with a recommendation from someone you trust) or unless their client company gives them a company email address to use. The reality is that anyone with an internet connection can become a recruiter nowadays. They can be like spammers. The barrier to entry is super low. But you don't need them. Use your own network of friends and professionals, use LinkedIn, use meetup, use AngelList, but do not use 3rd party recruiters (except for the two exceptions I've made above).

Comment: @StephanBranczyk, its funny last night I came to the same conclusion about "anyone with an internet connection can become a recruiter". I remember one recruiter took all my info including who I have interview with and the next day posted that info as if they were representing that employer. I contacted the employer I had interviewed with to verify and learned that they had no connection to any such recruitment firm and were only doing direct hire themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Target well networked people, do their jobs cheaply with no issues, go the extra mile.

Then sit back and watch people knocking on your door. Then pick the ones out of those that have similar marketing power. Once you have your foot in the door with the right circles, you just relax and let them come to you.

Once the ball is rolling you just focus on providing excellent service.

Well networked people doesn't necessarily mean top executives in corporations, it can be financial controllers and owners of relatively small businesses. Most of my later IT career was done this way, I've spent zero on formal advertising.

Answer (score -3):

Unfortunately the one and only answer is experience.

You need to be able to say "I did this, this, this, and this."  Those have to be **real paying clients**, and, moreover, they have to be **well-known** or even household names.

Unfortunately: that's it.

That's it in total and, unfortunately, there's nothing else.

*One fact*: if you *contract* - so, working on 3 or 4 or even more different products each year, you will be able to say "I did this, this, this and this" much more quickly than if you take full-time jobs. With full-time jobs it can easliy take you five years to have just **three** "this"s; with contracting in five years you will have a vast array of "this"s.  (Of course, the catch-22 is that contracting only goes to the best and most experienced, with the longest list of "this"s :/ )

Coming back to this,

> You need to be able to say "I did this, this, this, and this." Unfortunately, there's nothing else.

Other things that help *to an extremely small degree* are

1. If you have superb, just superlative, essays or similar online, or perhaps if you have published books, which are the leading most recognized articles or books in the field, that helps to a ***small*** degree.  I emphasize ***small*** and this is only as an ancillary matter, if you are already able to say "I did this, this, this and this". Unfortunately.
2. If you have made a major, I mean one of the top 10, libraries (I mean at the level of like, you're the guy who made the original GPUImage or such), again that helps to a ***small*** degree.  I emphasize ***small*** and this is only as an ancillary matter, if you are already able to say "I did this, this, this and this". Unfortunately.

Actually the key points of 1 and 2 is that they *don't* help.  20 years ago, folks would say "Be sure to have some open source contributions or libraries out there, it may help you get started!"  Very unfortunately, today, **nobody cares** about "sample project", hobby projects, etc.

Very unfortunately, you need to be able to say "I did this, this, this, and this." Unfortunately, there's nothing else.

## Gatekeepers

OP, you're now essentially referring to the difficulty of **getting past gatekeepers**.,

This problem exists in all of business.

Over and over I have the situation where it is insanely hard to "get past the gatekeepers", and when I finally do, the founder of the company says "why didn't you contact me sooner"

### DOH.

That happens all the time. It's business.

I recommend studying all of these excellent books,

[http://amazon.com/Getting-Past-Gatekeeper-Greatest-Enemy-ebook/dp/B01HDUQKS0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01HDUQKS0)

[http://amazon.com/Key-Gate-Gatekeepers-business-business-ebook/dp/B00KYI4T1E](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00KYI4T1E)

http://thriftbooks.com/w/get-past-the-gatekeeper-and-straight-to-the-decision-maker_tom-mallens/17645809

[http://amazon.com/How-Get-Meeting-Anyone-Marketing/dp/1941631789](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1941631789)

http://thriftbooks.com/w/storyselling-the-science-of-winning-sales-through-the-power-of-emotional-connection_michael-bosworth_ben-zoldan/771137/item/4293826

[http://amazon.com/dp/1594487154](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1594487154)

[http://amazon.com/dp/1570715882](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1570715882)

For example, a retired family member was one of those "Sales training" author / motivational speaker type guys. (BTW this sucks, occasionally I'd meet people who would rant about how he Changed Their Life etc, and ignore me!) One of his main courses was "getting past the gatekeeper".

As Richard Bach explains, for any problem in life ....... there are:  **Books**.  Any problem you have, clarify it and then read all the excellent books by people who have done vast, often lifetimes, of research on the exact problem at hand, and have subsequently written books on exactly the problem.

You can easily resolve the gatekeeper problem (as I have) and make it a huge advantage.

### My secret tip - don't tell anyone:

How to get past gatekeepers - say, recruiters - in the programming milieu:

It's very simple and non-mysterious.  Simply, in your cv or similar, **heavily *emphasize* the *expertise* at hand**.  It's non-mystetious.

Note that I am not suggesting in any way fibbing or even exaggerating. I'm just talking about basically *typographical* issues.  Think about it:

(A) The gatekeeper has been tasked with one thing: *finding someone who is expert with gpus*. But (B) the gatekeeper is not an expert in that field or even the general field, "gpu" is nothing more than a strange word.

Change the heading of your CV from

Product lead

to

GPU industry leading GPU expert with GPU speciality.

Then rewrite each line item as:  "GPU programmer on the GPU Peleton GPU app, working on the GPU."  "Team GPU lead on GPU project at GPU division of Apple's GPU center, led GPU team"  "GPU senior contractor at GPU Raytheon"  "Senior GPU architecture and GPU engineer on GPU team at GPU division of well-known GPU product FastGPU"

And so on.

When you say hello on zoom, say "Hi, I'm always looking for the next GPU challenge."

Put on a a GPU themed sweatshirt. Throw in to conversation factoids like the latest GPU version and the names of GPUs. Pick up a device and mention the GPU in it.

It's really that simple. **The gatekeeper just wants to tick the box on the speciality.**

Just bear in mind the two salient facts about gatekeepers,

(A) they're seeking some speciality, they just have to **tick that box** and you're away

(B) they know nothing about that technically, so - almost humorously - just literally emphasize those words.

The single-step trick is, very simply, change the headline of your cv, "what you are", from "senior programmer" to ">speciality< programmer".

Enjoy!

Comment: I have been contracting since 2017 which has given me the "I did this, this and this" just like you shared. What I find odd is, when I am sharing that with a recruiter, sometimes I feel like they are not even paying attention or have a clue what I am talking about, like they are just going through the motions, which really bugs me and I usually distance myself from that type of recruiter. Second, I find that some places take my contracting experience as, "can't hold down one job". Er, did you notice they are contracts? I make it clear they are contracts.

Comment: I guess what I am asking is, at what point does "I did this and this and this" get me in front of the serious decision maker, the person who writes the checks and not somebody just going through the motions.

Comment: @Daniel - AHHHH!  Recruiters are totally useless.  Treat them as a nuisance.  Everyone has to deal with them sometime.  Grin and bear it.

Comment: @Daniel - you're now essentially referring to the difficulty of **getting past gatekeepers**.  See edit

Comment: @Daniel - added more for you

Comment: yes recruiters. There are some that are serious, but a lot are useless. I did not know everyone had to deal with them, but I guess I was also asking, how do I get to the point where I just get serious decision-makers in front of me. Like, "oh yeah I heard about him, he can do x, can we get him?" Or is that unrealistic in the sense that, its a saturated market so really hard to be niche.

Comment: What I mean is, you don't HAVE to deal with recruiters, sure, no reason to.  (I rarely do.)  My point was just "when you deal with recruiters, they are a pain equally for everyone!"

Comment: "oh yeah I heard about him, he can do x, can we get him?"  You can never achieve that, the market is simply too large.  You mean being as famous as Paul McCartney.  So, "we need a guitarist - what about Joe Walsh".  The music industry is tiny, a handful of labels, a few hundred studios, a few thousand top musicians.  The software industry is basically "all of modern industry".  It's not possible to be "famous" like that.

Comment: I figured as much, but I like the funny twist you put to it. Also, I find a lot of good people out there that I would love to work with don't really respect the technology. They just need this website or that application and have no clue and probably do not care whether one person over the other is most effective at recording updates with optimistic concurrency control. Now that I think about it probably only a world that those that know NASAs proprietary programming language have.